# Switch off drag and drop feature of Google image search

Tags: google-search, google-image-search

How do I turn off Google's drag and drop image-based search feature?

When you go to the Google Image search engine, people can drop a picture into the search box and the results of the search will be displayed.

How do I switch off this feature?

Comment: No answer still now :(

Comment: Why do you want to disable it btw? By disable, do you mean you want to use the old image search UI?

Comment: Ya i want to use the old image search UI.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the old image search UI"? Would the current "basic version" (Scroll to the bottom and click "Switch to basic version" to see it) be acceptable? (It still has drag-and-drop, but behaves like the old UI otherwise as far as I can see) If so, I can probably whip up a solution to automatically force searches to basic UI for you.

Comment: We conducting a competition, where the user will be given a pic and he have to guess it and type it in google search engine to find the name of the image. So now i want to turn off so that user can't just drag and put it to find answer

Comment: Won't it be easier to use another search engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. The [Advanced Image Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_image_search) doesn't have drag-and-drop, so you could block access to the  Image Search home page and force everyone to use advanced.
2. You could whip up a page that uses the (deprecated) [Google Image Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/). It provides a JavaScript interface to embed Google Image Search results in your website or application.

   - Example from the Code Playground: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=image#size_restriction
3. Search by Image is [Firefox and Chrome only](http://lifehacker.com/5812272/how-to-enable-and-start-using-googles-with-keyboard+less-search-by-voice-and-image). You could make everyone use Safari, or... another browser.

Hopefully one of these methods should suit.

Comment: here we go :D Your 100 points :D

Comment: @cliaran : and in IE older version **Search by Image** is not working? Sure?

Comment: "Search by Image is compatible with the following browsers:

Chrome
Firefox 3.0+
Internet Explorer 8+
Safari 5.0+" http://images.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1325808&p=searchbyimagepage